# Android When testing my app on other devices only some seem to pick up my drawables

Tags: android, bitmap

I'm trying to test my app with simple animations on all the densities, but when testing the high and low density phones on the emulator (Nexus One 4.2.2 for hdpi, and WQVGA 4.2.2 for ldpi) my bitmaps aren't drawn. I have doubled check that I named the bitmap the same for all the folders, as well as scaled them appropriately and that doesn't seem to help anything. If it helps, I am using this example to adjust the sizes individually.

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
switch(metrics.densityDpi){
 case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
            break;
 case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
             break;
 case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
             break;
}
```

And here is my logcat:

```
07-24 03:32:53.424: E/Trace(822): error opening trace file: No such file or directory     (2)
07-24 03:32:54.514: D/dalvikvm(822): GC_CONCURRENT freed 33K, 6% free 2774K/2932K,     paused 18ms+17ms, total 132ms
07-24 03:32:54.574: D/dalvikvm(822): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6K, 6% free 2845K/2996K, paused    27ms, total 28ms
07-24 03:32:54.584: I/dalvikvm-heap(822): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.500MB for 635812-byte allocation
07-24 03:32:54.636: D/dalvikvm(822): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 5% free 3466K/3620K, paused 48ms, total 48ms
07-24 03:32:54.684: D/dalvikvm(822): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 5% free 3470K/3620K, paused 18ms+5ms, total 48ms
07-24 03:32:54.684: D/dalvikvm(822): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 19ms
07-24 03:32:54.694: I/dalvikvm-heap(822): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.968MB for 1536016-byte allocation
07-24 03:32:54.744: D/dalvikvm(822): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 4% free 4970K/5124K, paused 43ms, total 44ms
07-24 03:32:55.405: I/Choreographer(822): Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-24 03:32:55.424: D/gralloc_goldfish(822): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
07-24 03:32:55.815: I/Choreographer(822): Skipped 64 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Error You are Facing is Because You are Doing Too Much work on your Main Thread. Use ASYNC TASKS to achieve this purpose do all background work in there and then onPostExecute show the Results. Secondly if the bitmap or drawable size is too large it would not render properly and not show resulting in sometimes OutofMemory exception and other. Currently what i am seeing on your log file is that you are doing too much work on the UIThread which is not a good Practise and blocks app operations resulting in ANR i.e. application not responding.

Comment: That makes me laugh a little because my "animation" is just a small object slowly moving across the screen. Anyway, to achieve what I have, I followed a tutorial that had me create the animation in View, and later stated that it may be better to use SurfaceView instead. Is that necessary, or would following the ASYNC TASKS suffice? On a side note, why is it that it works fine in MDPI, even though that has less ram than the HDPI?